# Mongoose document.save() method is blocking websocket execution

Tags: node.js, mongoose, websocket

I have a NodeJS app running a websocket server using the ws npm package. In a callback from the message event `ws.on("message", async (rawData, isBinary) => {})`, I'm trying to update a document and then save it. The .find() method works fine, but the .save() method blocks execution completely.

```js
const users = await Promise.all(
    game.players.map((p) => User.findById(p.id)) // This works fine
);

// mess with users here

await Promise.all(users.map(u => u.save())) // <-- This doesn't work
await users[0].save() // <--- This doesn't work either
users[0].save((err, doc) => {
   // This doesn't work either
})
users[0].save().then(doc => {
    // console.log(doc) // <-- This doesn't work either
})
```

For starters, is this even possible ? Or am I thinking about it the wrong way and should I trigger some kind of POST request from the client to hit my http server instead to do the mongodb operations ? In any case, I'm struggling to understand why this is not possible.

Also something interesting is when I tried logging everything everywhere I tried to do the following

```js
console.log(users[0].save())
users[0].save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) console.log(err) // <-- no log here
    console.log(doc) // <-- no log here
})
```

which threw mongoose's `ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel`. So I'm guessing the action does take place but not entirely ?

Any insight on this is welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting an unhandled promise rejection. Try adding [unhandledrejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) event listener

Comment: BTW. You should be using `find( { _id: { $in: user_ids } } )` and `insertMany`. Don't use one-by-one map , find/insert queries. That is probably one reason why it blocks longer than you want, and raises a parallel error